# Print text with html tags from database - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, parsing, decode

I am using CKEditor in my React App to save user content into the Firebase database. Content is saved as I want it (eg. with html tags 
`"<p>contentheheheh</p>\n"`
) but the problem occurs when I want to fetch the data.

As a result of fetch, let's say into a  of  I get text with html tags, not 'converted' into bold or italic for example.

When I get into Chrome console and inspect  element I see something like this:

```
<td>&lt;p&gt;I am&amp;nbsp;&lt;strong&gt;testing&amp;nbsp;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;em&gt;text&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

The thing is I worked with 'raw' db inputs before in Laravel or Symphony, but I don't know how to do it in javascript. I tried to look for it in google and stack but to be honest I failed because I don't even know what exactly is a question, since 'fetch raw data from db in javascript' didn't worked exactly as I imagined.

Thanks for any advice in advance.

P.S. I know that in Jquery there was something like this:

```
var text = '&lt;p&gt;name&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="font-size:xx-small;"&gt;ajde&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;da&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;';
var decoded = $('<textarea/>').html(text).text();
alert(decoded);
```

But I don't know how to write this in pure javascript (or ES6).

Answer (score 1):

Okey so I spent at this problem whole night BEFORE I asked the question, and just after I did that, I managed to resolve the problem.

1. I installed 'he' library from npm package (npm install he)
2. I installed 'html-react-parser' (npm install html-react-parser).

First one is used to decode html from database. Second one is to write this html into jsx elements.

Example:

```
let text = he.decode(props.tdData[item]);
return (<td>{Parser(text)}</td>);
```

This two libraries do it for me and it works just as I wanted.

Thanks for any input you made, case is closed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with RegExp replacement:

```
var text = '&lt;p&gt;I am&amp;nbsp;&lt;strong&gt;testing&amp;nbsp;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;em&gt;text&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;';

var decoded = text.replace(/"&amp;/g, "&").replace(/&gt;/g, ">").replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&quot;/g, "\"");
```

Comment: I use ckeditor in CMS system and I don't think that I even want to 'decode' like this. I mean I would need to 'replace' EVERY tag that exist in CKEditor right? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Fact is that this is longer version, but the one that i tried. You can make a map of equivalent pairs and create regexp from a function that will accept matching pairs (still needs to map all symbols)

Comment: Yeah and that could be painful :D Thankfully there's "he' library which did it for me :)

Comment: Cool, glad you found solution :D Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Probably (without code sample i can't really know) the cause of what is happening doesn't come from fetch but from rendering.

By default react escapes html tags when rendering a component.

To avoid escaping and set html of a component use dangerouslysetinnerhtml (
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml ).

Comment: I read about 'dangerously..' and many prople claimed that is, well, dangerous. They adviced to use 'html-react-parser' instead. To decode html stored in db I use 'he' library, also very nice and simple. I will post what I've done in 5-10 minutes. But thanks for advice!

Comment: You're welcome.
Yes of course as per documentation it may expose security risks that depends on the way you are doing the fetch part and how db is populated.
IMHO xss risks should be avoided on what is in db and how js is talking to db.
Of course your final solution is more secure, but it still decodes and parse it back something that should be "already ready" for dom as per server-side checks (in this specific scenario).